# Are there any exceptions to Ruby convention of boolean methods having a question mark (?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For methods that return a boolean value it seems normal to end the call in a ?, but in some code I've seen this is not consistently done. For example, some functions such as `create` and `save` do not have ? at the end in some code I've seen.

Is this bad practice/inconsistent. Should it be everywhere where a boolean is returned? Or is it occasionally omitted?

Answer (score 5):

The ActiveRecord `save` method doesn't ask a question, it merely performs an action and returns the status of the requested action. That the return value (i.e. status) is boolean is immaterial.

Methods such as `Array#include?` or `String#start_with?` do ask questions so they have the `?` suffixes on their names.

So it isn't the return value that determines whether or not the method name ends with a question mark, it is the method's intent: if calling the method is primarily asking a yes/no question then it gets a question mark; if calling the method primarily does something else then it doesn't get a question mark even if it just happens to return a boolean value.

---

Of course reality isn't that simple.

[`File.size?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-size-3F) returns `nil` or `Integer` and to further confuse matters, there is also [`File.size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-size) which returns `Integer`. Both of these ask a question -- "What is the size of the file with name **X**?" -- the only difference is that `File.size?` returns `nil` if the file doesn't exist or has size zero (sigh) whereas `File.size` has no specified behavior for non-existent files. Then there's [`File#size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-i-size) (but no `File#size?`) as an instance method on the same class, `File#size` asks the same question as `File.size` and `File.size?` but has no question mark.

Then over in `Float` we have:

- [`infinite?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-infinite-3F) which asks a yes/no question but returns `nil`, `-1`, or `+1`.
- [`nan?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-nan-3F) and [`zero?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html#method-i-zero-3F) which ask yes/no questions and return `true` or `false`.

There are other examples (such as the oddly named `defined?` operator, [`Set#add?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) vs [`Set#add`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add), [`Set#delete?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-delete-3F) vs [`Set#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-delete), ...) where a `?`-method doesn't return a boolean value but they are exceptions and stand out because they are inconsistent with the usual core behavior.

We could even bring up `attr_reader`. If you say:

```
attr_reader :pancakes
```

then you get a `pancakes` method which you can use to ask the question "what is the value of the `pancakes` property?". Note that you don't get `pancakes?` method to ask that question, you just get a `pancakes` accessor method.

The behavior of `?`-methods in the core is somewhat inconsistent but the numbers strongly lean toward "asks a question with a yes or no answer". As far as non-core code is concerned, people can do whatever they want so no doubt there is vast inconsistency there.

Comment: Methods that end in `?` don't even always return a boolean value, sometimes they return e.g. `nil` or something true-ish other than `true`. The important part is the "asking questions" part, not whether the method literally returns only the two special objects `true` and `false`. It's not method but an operator, so it doesn't fit the question 100%, but on some Ruby implementations, the unary prefix `defined?` operator returns a string describing the kind of entity you are asking about such as `'local-variable'` or `'method'` and `nil` otherwise. It will never return `true` or `false`.

Comment: There is [`Kernel#autoload?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload-3F) in the standard library. That said, the behavior of not returning a strict boolean is much more common in user code. Generally, you should just expect a question-mark method to return a truthy/falsy value unless explicitly documented otherwise. This is eg. rather common in Rails where the actual return of a strict true/false is not so common at all.

Comment: [File::size?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/File.html#method-c-size-3F) returns the size or `nil`, [Set#add?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-add-3F) and [Set#delete?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-delete-3F) return self or `nil`

Comment: @Stefan: But `File.size` returns the size as does `File#size` and there is no `File#size?` at all. So that is rather inconsistent. And those Set methods don't even really ask questions, do they?

Comment: @HolgerJust: We should expect user code to be all over the place and inconsistent. The fact that there are so few non-booleans in the core suggests that non-boolean `?`-methods are oddballs (nevermind the complete mess of size methods in `File`). The "ends with ?" naming convention is rather inconsistent but leans heavily towards boolean returns.

Comment: Well, Ruby has a strictly defined small set of falsy values, i.e. `false` and `nil`. It's just reasonable to assume that a predicate method (with a question mark) returns a value suitable for a truthyness check, the exact return value is not that important *This* is what people actually build. The fact that most of the stdlib predicate methods return `true` or `false` is merely caused by their implementation in C and their typically very basic checks.

Comment: @HolgerJust The naming is still very inconsistent and a bit of a mess (`File.size` vs `File.size?` for example). As far as the C goes, it is just as easy to use `Qnil` instead of `Qfalse` or a literal `1` instead of `Qtrue` so I'm not sure what relevance the implementation language has. I've always used *predicate* in the mathematical sense where predicates are defined as returning booleans. Usually, `x?` indicates a mathematical predicate, sometimes it marks a variant (`File.size` vs `File.size?` and the `Set` methods), sometimes it is just lazy "two things at once" (`Float#infinite?`).

Answer (score 0):

I think the convention is to use a "`?`" if you are just querying to check if something is true.

For example:

```
def is_a_jerk?(user)
  user == "nPn" ? true : false
end
```

while something like `save` will return true if it was successful, but will return false if not.

Comment: `user == "nPn"` does exactly the same as the ternary.